# code: 'InvalidAuthenticationToken', message: 'CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217' - Microsoft AD Graph API

Tags: node.js, axios, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying the following :
const url = `API URL`

```
    accesstokenrefreshed = i got this from another api.
    adsaccountuser = await axios.get(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accesstokenrefreshed}`,
    'Accept' : 'application/json', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Host': 'graph.microsoft.com' } })
```

But when i use this code i get error - 'CompactToken parsing failed with error code' but it is working fine in POstman. Can anyone suggest a solution to this. how we can fix it. the token is seen in the logs correctly.

Comment: This error means the token is not properly added. Check if the value `accesstokenrefreshed`  actually has something. I have tested this exact code by assigning  `accesstokenrefreshed`  to a token and I don't see `CompactToken parsing failed with error code`

Comment: hi , @dansan  var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abs.test.com',
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesstokenvalue}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    console.log(config.headers)
    let res = await axios(config)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this, your code works fine when I have a variable `accesstokenrefreshed` assigned to an access token. Please check what value the `accesstokenrefreshed` is before the request runs. I think the token is being sent in an invalid state. Check if there is an extra space between `Bearer` and `Token`